# Python argparse: Create timedelta object from argument?

Tags: python, argparse, timedelta

I am attempting to use `argparse` to convert an argument into a `timedelta` object. My program reads in strings supplied by the user and converts them to various `datetime` objects for later usage. I cannot get the `filter_length` argument to process correctly though. My code:

```
import datetime
import time
import argparse

def mkdate(datestring):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(datestring, '%Y-%m-%d').date()

def mktime(timestring):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(timestring, '%I:%M%p').time()

def mkdelta(deltatuple):
    return datetime.timedelta(deltatuple)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('start_date', type=mkdate, nargs=1)
parser.add_argument('start_time', type=mktime, nargs=1, )
parser.add_argument('filter_length', type=mkdelta, nargs=1, default=datetime.timedelta(1))#default filter length is 1 day.
```

I run the program, passing `1` as the `timedelta` value (I only want it to be one day):

```
> python program.py 2012-09-16 11:00am 1
```

But I get the following error:

```
>>> program.py: error: argument filter_length: invalid mkdelta value: '1'
```

I don't understand why the value is invalid. If I call the mkdelta function on its own, like this:

```
mkdelta(1)
print mkdelta(1)
```

It returns:

```
datetime.timedelta(1)
1 day, 0:00:00
```

This is exactly the value that I'm looking for. Can someone help me figure out how to do this conversion properly using `argparse`?

Answer (score 7):

Notice the quotes around `'1'` in your error message?  You pass a string to mkdelta, whereas in your test code, you pass an integer.

Comment: How could I go about passing a non string object as an argument?

Comment: In your test code simply type `mkdelta('1')`. Otherwise adapt your code as Martijn Pieters has suggested, by casting deltatuple to an int.

Comment: Also, may I suggest that, if you do so, you rename deltatuple?

Answer (score 6):

Your function doesn't handle a string argument, which is what argparse is handing it; call `int()` on it:

```
def mkdelta(deltatuple):
    return datetime.timedelta(int(deltatuple))
```

If you need to support more than days, you'll have to find a way to parse the argument passed in into timedelta arguments.

You could, for example, support `d`, `h`, `m` or `s` postfixes to denote days, hours, minutes or seconds:

```
_units = dict(d=60*60*24, h=60*60, m=60, s=1)
def mkdelta(deltavalue):
    seconds = 0
    defaultunit = unit = _units['d']  # default to days
    value = ''
    for ch in list(str(deltavalue).strip()):
        if ch.isdigit():
            value += ch
            continue
        if ch in _units:
            unit = _units[ch]
            if value:
                seconds += unit * int(value)
                value = ''
                unit = defaultunit
            continue
        if ch in ' \t':
            # skip whitespace
            continue
        raise ValueError('Invalid time delta: %s' % deltavalue)
    if value:
        seconds = unit * int(value)
    return datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)
```

Now your `mkdelta` method accepts more complete deltas, and even integers still:

```
>>> mkdelta('1d')
datetime.timedelta(1)
>>> mkdelta('10s')
datetime.timedelta(0, 10)
>>> mkdelta('5d 10h 3m 10s')
datetime.timedelta(5, 36190)
>>> mkdelta(5)
datetime.timedelta(5)
>>> mkdelta('1')
datetime.timedelta(1)
```

The default unit is days.

Comment: So, this does work, however, it only allows me to specify dates to the function. It actually doesnt support the full timedelta notation:([days[, seconds[, microseconds[, milliseconds[, minutes[, hours[, weeks]]]]]]]). I need to be able to pass the full range of datetime values as the argument. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You'd have to invent a text format for that, or use multiple command line switches, then parse that into arguments for a timedelta object.

Comment: Why would you need to support full timedelta notation? In your requirements you say you only need the day part. If you want your user to specify more flags, you need to pass nargs='?'. This way the mkdelta will receive a string with the remaining arguments.

Comment: In this case, 1 day is the default, but I might need to specify a different timedelta value if I want the duration of the program's output to be longer or shorter. The task can vary. I also cannot instruct it to consume all remaining arguments, because I have other arguments that I need to pass to the program later that are not part of the timedelta I need to specify.

Comment: @user1675914: I've invented a format for you; add units as needed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a custom action to collect all the remaining args and parse them into a `timedelta`.

This will allow you to write CLI commands such as

```
% test.py 2012-09-16 11:00am 2 3 4 5
datetime.timedelta(2, 3, 5004)   # args.filter_length
```

You could also provide optional arguments for `--days`, `--seconds`, etc, so you can write CLI commands such as

```
% test.py 2012-09-16 11:00am --weeks 6 --days 0
datetime.timedelta(42)           # args.filter_length

% test.py 2012-09-16 11:00am --weeks 6.5 --days 0
datetime.timedelta(45, 43200)
```

---

```
import datetime as dt
import argparse

def mkdate(datestring):
    return dt.datetime.strptime(datestring, '%Y-%m-%d').date()

def mktime(timestring):
    return dt.datetime.strptime(timestring, '%I:%M%p').time()

class TimeDeltaAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, args, values, option_string = None):
        # print '{n} {v} {o}'.format(n = args, v = values, o = option_string)
        setattr(args, self.dest, dt.timedelta(*map(float, values)))

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('start_date', type = mkdate)
parser.add_argument('start_time', type = mktime)
parser.add_argument('--days', type = float, default = 1)
parser.add_argument('--seconds', type = float, default = 0)
parser.add_argument('--microseconds', type = float, default = 0)
parser.add_argument('--milliseconds', type = float, default = 0)
parser.add_argument('--minutes', type = float, default = 0)
parser.add_argument('--hours', type = float, default = 0)
parser.add_argument('--weeks', type = float, default = 0)
parser.add_argument('filter_length', nargs = '*', action = TimeDeltaAction)

args = parser.parse_args()
if not args.filter_length:
    args.filter_length = dt.timedelta(
        args.days, args.seconds, args.microseconds, args.milliseconds,
        args.minutes, args.hours, args.weeks)
print(repr(args.filter_length))
```

Answer (score 0):

This gist seems to solve your problem: https://gist.github.com/jnothman/4057689

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody lands here looking to add a `pandas.Timedelta` to an argument parser (as I just did), it turns out the following works just fine:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--timeout', type=pd.Timedelta)
```

Then:

```py
>>> parser.parse_args(['--timeout', '24 hours'])
Namespace(timeout=Timedelta('1 days 00:00:00'))
```

Answer (score 0):

To add onto Martijn's beautiful answer, here's a variant of the function he posted, extended to work with weeks, months and even years. It's a tiny bit more complicated because it needs to handle multi-character time units, but I think the added complexity is worth the extra functionality. It's also been ported to Python 3. Here it is

```py
import datetime


def parse_delay_into_timedelta(delta: str):
    second = 1
    minute = second * 60
    hour = minute * 60
    day = hour * 24
    week = day * 7
    month = week * 4
    year = month * 12
    units = {"s": second,
             "m": minute,
             "h": hour,
             "d": day,
             "w": week,
             "mo": month,
             "y": year}
    # We need this to handle multi-character units
    # like months
    longest = max(len(k) for k in units.keys())
    seconds = 0
    default_unit = unit = units['d']  # Defaults to days
    value = ""
    delta = delta.strip().lower()
    i = 0
    while i < len(delta):
        ch = delta[i]
        i += 1
        # isdigit will return True even for things like numbers
        # in Arabic and stuff. For my use case this is undesirable,
        # but if you care about that, just swap isnumeric() for isdigit()
        if ch.isnumeric():
            value += ch
        # Only restrict ourselves to ASCII letters. Again, this is specific
        # to my use-case. Can edit as necessary
        elif ch.isalpha() and ch.isascii():
            unit_name = ch
            j = i
            # Try to parse as many characters of the unit as possible,
            # but stop once we either reach the end of the string or
            # the length of the current (potential) unit equals the
            # length of the longest one we know
            while j < len(delta) and len(unit_name) < longest:
                if (char := delta[j]).isalpha() and char.isascii():
                    unit_name += char
                else:
                    break
                j += 1
            # If the unit was more than one character long, we
            # have to skip the next len(unit_name) - 1 characters,
            # so we don't try to parse 'mo' and then 'o' again, for
            # example. If the unit was one character long, this value
            # will just be zero
            i += len(unit_name) - 1
            try:
                unit = units[unit_name]
            except KeyError:
                raise ValueError(f"invalid unit {unit_name!r}")
            if value:
                seconds += unit * int(value)
                value = ""
                unit = default_unit
        elif ch in ' \t\r':
            # Skip useless characters
            continue
        else:
            # Unknown character
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid character {ch!r} in time delta: {delta!r}")
    if value:
        seconds = unit * int(value)

    return datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)
```

You can use it like this:

```py
>>> parse_delay_into_timedelta("2y 1mo 1w 5d 6m 1h 3s")
datetime.timedelta(days=712, seconds=3963)
>>> parse_delay_into_timedelta("1s")
datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
>>> parse_delay_into_timedelta("10s")
datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)
>>> parse_delay_into_timedelta("15h")
datetime.timedelta(seconds=54000)
```

**P.S.**: Note that, for simplicity reasons, the function assumes all months are a clean multiple of 4 weeks and all years are a clean multiple of 12 months, which isn't exactly the case (leap years and stuff), but for what I needed this is fine. Be aware of that though!